# Setting a price for a payable function (Ethereum Pet Shop)

Tags: solidity, metamask

I'm following the [Ethereum Pet Shop](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop) tutorial online, and everything works fine. However, to "adopt" a pet, the MetaMask transaction on my site is only requiring me to pay for the gas. I've taken a look at the Solidity docs and I think I'm supposed to make my function "payable", which I've tried, but actually setting a required price in wei to execute the contract is unclear to me.

Here's my `Adoption.sol` file:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Adoption {
    address[16] public adopters;
    // Adopting a pet
    function adopt(uint petId) public payable returns (uint) {
        require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);

        adopters[petId] = msg.sender;

        return petId;
    }
    // Retrieving the adopters
    function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16]) {
        return adopters;
    }

}
```

And my `TestAdoption.sol` file:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/Adoption.sol";

contract TestAdoption {
    Adoption adoption = Adoption(DeployedAddresses.Adoption());

    //Testing the adopt() function
    function testUserCanAdoptPet() public {
      uint returnedId = adoption.adopt(8);
      uint expected = 8;
      Assert.equal(returnedId, expected, "Adoption of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");
    }

    // Testing retrieval of a single pet's owner
    function testGetAdopterAddressByPetId() public {
        // Expected owner is this contract
        address expected = this;
        address adopter = adoption.adopters(8);
        Assert.equal(adopter, expected, "Owner of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");
    }

    // Testing retrieval of all pet owners
    function testGetAdopterAddressByPetIdInArray() public {
        // Expected owner is this contract
        address expected = this;

        // Store adopters in memory rather than contract's storage
        address[16] memory adopters = adoption.getAdopters();

        Assert.equal(adopters[8], expected, "Owner of pet ID 8 should be recorded.");
    }

}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MetaMask transaction prompt is opened by your JavaScript code not your Solidity code. If you want it to include a default value you will have to add that value in your JavaScript, by adding it as a `value` parameter to your call to `adopt()`.

To enforce payment as a *requirement* for adoption, you will also need to add some code to your Solidity `adopt()` function to check `msg.value` and throw an error if it's lower than however much it's supposed to be. You may also want to add a read-only `constant` function to tell the user how much they have to pay, then call that from your JavaScript code to fetch the value that you will then set as the default that will be displayed by MetaMask.

Comment: So my call to `adopt()` looks like this now: `return adoptionInstance.adopt(petId, value="1000", {from: account});`, but when I try to click on "Adopt" on the page, I get an error in the console saying "Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function". Do I have to update `function adopt(uint petId)` to something like `function adopt(uint petId, uint value)` or something like that? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: Try return `adoptionInstance.adopt(petId, {from: account, value: 1000})`. Also note that the 1000 is in Wei, 1000 of which will be a very small number of ETH. I think MetaMask might end up rounding that down to 0, in which case you might like to try a grander number.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to add `payable`, as it looks like you did. Then you just need to check that the right amount of ether was sent. E.g.:

```
require(msg.value == priceInWei);
```

If you want adopting a pet to cost 1 ether, then you can do:

```
require(msg.value == 1 ether);
```

Note that you'll also have to change your tests to send ether along. E.g.:

```
adoption.adopt.value(1 ether)(8);
```

Comment: and how about the JavaScript that Edmund mentioned? I'm trying to pass a value to adopt() but the MetaMask UI now shows all of the values to be 0.

Comment: I don't use Truffle myself, but I believe it should be `adoptionInstance.adopt(petId, { value: 1000, from: account });` (Replace 1000 with whatever price you're requiring. E.g. `web3.toWei(1, 'ether')`.)